# Cannot find module @babel/preset-polyfill

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to use @babel/preset-polyfill with webpack 4 as following:

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react", "@babel/polyfill"]
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [{
          loader: "html-loader",
          options: {
            minimize: true
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html",
      filename: "./index.html"
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css"
    })
  ]
};
```

the compiler complains:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-polyfill' from '/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate'
- If you want to resolve "@babel/polyfill", use "module:@babel/polyfill"
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/resolve/lib/sync.js:42:15)
    at resolveStandardizedName (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:100:31)
    at resolvePreset (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:57:10)
    at loadPreset (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js:76:20)
    at createDescriptor (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:135:21)
    at items.map (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:87:50)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at createDescriptors (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:87:29)
    at createPresetDescriptors (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:79:10)
    at passPerPreset (/Volumes/Develop/html/ReactReasonTemplate/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/config-descriptors.js:71:96) @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src/index.js .
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to import ''babel-preset-env" or "babel-polyfill"? It looks like you have the pollyfill in the `presets` field but it should be in the `entry`.
https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/#usage-in-node--browserify--webpack

Answer (score 0):

work for me after removing '@babel/preset-polyfill' from "presets" in .babelrc file